# Websockets not working (ssl acceleration?)

Tags: ssl, load-balancing, socket

Testing a `socket.io` application in the PROD environment for the first time, we found that while the `xhr-polling` transport (Ajax long polling) works, the `websocket` transport does not.

Looking at the data transmitted using `Fiddler`, I can see that the

- `UPGRADE` happens and
- the first message from the server (5 bytes gross) arrive at the client.
- The client then sends a couple of messages to the server, which normally result in server->client messages

But those server->client messages never arrive (I'm not even sure if the client->server messages arrive on the server side). Eventually (after about 6 seconds), Fiddler reports a

```
Read from Server failed...
```

and a new connection gets established, as unsuccessful as the first one.

Our setup looks something like this:

Internet -> Firewall -> BIG-IP 3600 (terminates SSL) -> Node.js server

I'd think the firewall could not be the culprit, as all it sees is an SSL encrypted stream of data, and with a the non-websocket transport it does works. I also tried the `match origin protocol` option in `socket.io`, without success.

Unfortunately I cannot freely play in that environment, so I tried to replicate the issue in my DEV environment, without success. I created a software SSL proxy (using `node.js`'s `http-proxy`), which should work similar to BIG-IP. But going through that SSL proxy with websockets works just fine.

Could this a be an issue with the BIG-IP? Configuration? What else could it be?

Comment: As of December of 2012, BIG-IP doesn't support SSL offload of WebSocket traffic. How are you managing to do this?

Comment: Do you have any link where this issue is addressed? And maybe an explanation on why SSL offloading WebSockets would be an issue?

Comment: It's a direct quote when asked if it was supported. They said it was not and to submit a feature request through their support channel. The issue is that it thinks it's HTTP and doesn't recognize when the direction of flow changes.

Comment: Interesting. Wouldn't that also affect other transports like `chunked` http transfer, as used by socket.io's `htmlfile`, to do streaming (works only downstream: server -> client)

Comment: I assume it understands chunked transfer.

Comment: David, as your comments would completely explain my problem, would you just turn it into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of December of 2012, BIG-IP doesn't support SSL offload of WebSocket traffic. Because the requests look like HTTP, they're processed by an HTTP engine that doesn't understand when the direction of flow changes for a WebSocket connection. Don't use SSL offload with WebSocket connections until it's officially supported.

Comment: Couldn't something like [configuring ELB on TCP/SSL, instead of HTTP/HTTPS, makes the trick with WebSockets](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9210639/709537) be done with BIG-IPs?

Comment: I would think so.